# Load a new component on clicking a button in a table in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-component

I am pretty new to React and currently trying to achieve something very simple. I have a component

> Kiosk

that loads a table showing data. The table contains three buttons -

> Add, Edit and Delete

. What I am trying to achieve is to display a new component by clicking one of the buttons, such as -

> AddShelf, EditShelf, DeleteShelf

. Here is my code -
Kiosk.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Posts from "./Posts";
import Pagination from "../Pagination";

const Kiosk = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [postsPerPage] = useState(10);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await axios.get("http://192.168.29.135:8000/aysle/kiosks/");
      setPosts(res.data);
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);
  //Get current posts
  const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
  const currentPosts = posts.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);

  //Change Page
  const paginate = (pageNumber) => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

  //console.log(posts);
  return (
    <div>
      <Posts posts={currentPosts} loading={loading} />
      <Pagination
        postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
        totalPosts={posts.length}
        paginate={paginate}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Kiosk;
```

The table is rendered from a different component called Posts.js

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import edit from "../../images/edit.png";
import del from "../../images/delete.png";
import { Link, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";


    const Posts = ({ posts, loading, props }) => {
      if (loading) {
        return <h2>Loading All Kiosks....</h2>;
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <Link to="/kiosks/addkiosk">
            <button className="AddBtn" onClick={() => <AddKiosk />}>
              ADD
            </button>
          </Link>
          <table className="basket-view">
            <thead>
              <tr id="Baskettr">
                <th id="Basketth" colSpan="4">
                  Here are your Listings...
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr id="Baskettr">
                {/* <th id="Basketth">Id</th> */}
                <th id="Basketth">Kiosk Name</th>
                <th id="Basketth">Kiosk Location</th>
                <th id="Basketth">Kiosk Details</th>
                <th id="Basketth">Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="Baskettbody">
              {posts ? (
                posts.length > 0 ? (
                  posts.map((post, index) => {
                    return (
                      <tr id="Baskettr" key={index}>
                        {/* <td id="Baskettd">{basket.id}</td> */}
                        <td id="Baskettd">{post.kiosk_name}</td>
                        <td id="Baskettd">{post.kiosk_location}</td>
                        <td id="Baskettd">
                          <ul>
                            <li>Latitude: {post.kiosk_latitude}</li>
                            <li>Longitude: {post.kiosk_longitude}</li>
                            <li>IpAddress: {post.kiosk_ipaddress}</li>
                            <li>Mobile: {post.kiosk_mobile}</li>
                          </ul>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <button id="delBtn" title="Edit">
                            <img src={edit} id="BtnImg" alt="Edit" />
                          </button>
                          <Link to="/kiosks/delete">
                            <button id="editBtn" title="Delete">
                              <img src={del} id="BtnImg" alt="Delete" />
                            </button>
                          </Link>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    );
                  })
                ) : (
                  <tr id="Baskettr">
                    <td id="Baskettd">No Records to Show...</td>
                  </tr>
                )
              ) : (
                0
              )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Posts;
```

This is my AddShelf component which I would like to display on button click.
AddShelf.js

```
import React from "react";

export const AddShelf = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Hello from AddShelf</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have tried to add the link to the Button and render the component on click but the new component is not displayed. Also, I need the RowserRouter to be in this format. Example: If AddShelf Button is clicked the route should be:

> http://localhost:3000/kiosk/addkiosk

Similarly, for Edit Button the route should be:

> http://localhost:3000/kiosks/edit/:id

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, without the use of redux, to load a component on a button click is to save it in a state if the button was clicked and in render do an if statement to check if the button was clicked, if yes (true) => render it.

Now, if you wish that on button click would change the url and load a completly different component and unload the one you are loading right now with the use of routs, make your button into a `Link` element.

With the use of `Switch`, you can load different components based on URL

```
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/about">
        <About />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/users">
        <Users />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
```

^^^ That will load different components based on path.

```
<Link to="/">Home</Link>
<Link to="/about">About</Link>
<Link to="/users">Users</Link>
```

^^^ Will create a simple text clickable element that will change the url.

NOTE that these URL changes are on client side only. it will not fetch any new data from the backend, if you have it set up.

The same way you may pass the parameters, such as id

```
  <Route path="/User/:id">
    <User />
  </Route>
```

and inside the `User` component, to get the id

```
const { id } = useParams();
```

All these examples are taken from [reactrouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) website where you can read more about it.